# Node js response Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, server, apache2

I'm trying to make initial connection between my node js with apache2 web server backend to my React frontend. I'm newbie at all of this and trying to make it work on local machine before deployment.
I read about CORS and solve an issue with access origin headers with it, but I can't understand what am I missing here.

the server runs and listening to port 3000
the frontend on port 3001

**my frontend code is:**

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    persons: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      axios.get(`/ping`, {
          headers: {
              "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
          }
      })
          .then(res => {

              const persons = res.data;
              this.setState({ persons });
          })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <h1>dfdfdfdfdf{this.state.persons}</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

**And My Backend code is:**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');
var cors = require('cors');
var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(cors());
app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')))

app.get('/ping', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('pong')
})

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port, hostname, () => {
 console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

module.exports = app;
```

**I keep getting the errors:**

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
0.chunk.js:779
Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: Request failed with status code 404
(anonymous function) (0.chunk.js:779)
promiseReactionJob

Comment: You have a middleware setup like `app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});` , which creates an error . The error is passed down to next error handler middleware that responses as error. You can comment that middleware because it creates error without any condition.

Comment: It was a part of the problem, I've also had to change the url path. Thank you!